# SSH login without password and without keys

Tags: ssh, password, testing, ssh-keygen

Is it possible to configure a user to login via SSH without password and without using keys. Just typing "ssh user@server". I have tried some modifications with 
Match User  and with AllowUsers in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, but with no success. Perhaps
I'm not intending on using it on any servers. This is just for testing purposes locally on my virtual machines and to find out if it possible at all.

I have searched for this before posting but could not find the exact same question.

Comment: Try `rsh` instead ?

Comment: If you're on Linux instead of FreeBSD, the general steps are the same, but use `passwd -d <user>` instead of `pw usermod <user> -w none` to remove the user's password.

Comment: @Miro. Do you mean that you would like to ssh to a computer without the need ti enter password and user name every time?

Comment: @Goro, just without a password. I just want to know if there is way to make it. Without using Keys. I'm not intending to use it just wondering if there is way to set it up. Will try the suggestions above. Thanks for them guys.

Comment: Hi @Miro, please follow bellow and let me know it it worked if not we can find out why. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine, go to terminal and type the following:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh

$ ssh-keygen -t rsa # here just hit enter multiple times till terminal stop asking you any questions
```

Choose no passphrase when asked and accept the default filename of id_rsa

```
$ scp id_rsa.pub <user>@<yourhost>:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Provide your password when asked and that’s the last time you’ll have to do it!

[Reference](http://web.archive.org/web/20160404025901/http://jaybyjayfresh.com/2009/02/04/logging-in-without-a-password-certificates-ssh/)

Comment: @Christopher. Kindly would you please clarify? you can enter pass key and you can avoid doing that